# FTP File display works in filezilla, but lists blank in other apps? (Centos 6/vsftpd/ssh)

Tags: ssh, centos, ftp

So had to basically re install entire server, lost everything, but I am trying to add this one script that has a custom installer that uploads the FTP files directly through its self extracting program.

So whenever I use filezilla, (ssh), all files and things like that are displayed. Now when I go to the program and use just ftp, no files display.

[image: an img]
And here is what I get once it says it is connected through FTP:
![img!

Before hand, it shows a loader that it is accessing the directory.

So any help as to what I could do to resolve this issue?

It seems that SFTP works fine, but doing FTP wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this gladly.

Go into your vsftpd.conf file. Use any text editor you want..

I use nano so i'll do `nano /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

Then scroll to the very bottom and add the following line:

```
local_root=dir
```

dir is the place where you want FTP users to see first. I just  do the root of the server myself, which would just he a slash. `"/"`